# Неразбериха с кодировкой

Tags: html, база-данных

В phpmyadmin отображается некорректно когда добавляю запись на русском через сервер.

[image]

На сайте все отображаются некорректно, но когда добавляешь через чай то нормально отображаются русские буквы, но в phpmyadmin  так же некорректно.
Как мне исправить это, чтобы везде отображалось корректно?[image]

Последнею запись добавил через сайт. На сервере и на сайте ставил utf8, а в базе utf8_general_ci